# How to Check Only one RadioButton of a Row with Different Fileds binded in Row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have  a grid with 5 columns, in which 3 are RadioButtons of different fileds. I want to have a condition of checking only one radiobutton of that row,

My code is

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="DirectPOL">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdDirectPOL" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("POL"))%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="DirectPOD">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdDirectPOD" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("POD")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="inDirectPOL">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdIndirectPOL" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsPOL"))%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In doing this i can see all the three can be checked at one time, but i want to restrict it to one at a time...,
Can any one please help me

Comment: No i did that also but of No use

Answer (score 1):

Set the `GroupName` property:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="DirectPOL">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdDirectPOL" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("POL"))%>' 
        GroupName="Group1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="DirectPOD">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdDirectPOD" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("POD")) %>' 
        GroupName="Group1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="inDirectPOL">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdIndirectPOL" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsPOL"))%>' 
        GroupName="Group1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This way, only one `RadioButton` will be checked for each `RadioButton` with the same `GroupName`. In your case, you'll have to set one GroupName per row.